# SPWebApplication.WebConfigModifications.Count return zero when invoking in featureActivated?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-config, event-receiver, feature-activation

I am going to modify web.config in an event receiver project SharePoint 2016. I use this piece of code in FeatureActivated function to get access to the web.config to modify it:

```
SPWeb myWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
            SPWebApplication spWebApplication = myWeb.Site.WebApplication;
            Collection<SPWebConfigModification> webConfigCollection = spWebApplication.WebConfigModifications;
            int modCollectioncount = webConfigCollection.Count;
```

but this code `webConfigCollection.Count return zero. what is wrong with my way?

Comment: Is this piece of code executing before you do the modifications? If yes, then this is indeed right as you didn't add any custom `SPWebModification` to the `spWebApplication`'s  `SPWebService` yet. Otherwise please add the code that is adding the modifications.

Comment: This piece of code is executed before modifying the SPWebModification. But it does not return a sensible answer or something that I do not know!!!